# Convert List enumeration to formatted string

Tags: prolog

I am completely new to prolog and am trying to enumerate all possible binary trees with N nodes. I would like this to be output in the following format (this example would be for 2 nodes):

```
    (.(.))
    ((.).)
```

Right now I am getting the correct output but it is in the form of a prolog list, like so:

```
    [[], [[], []]]
    [[[], []], []]
```

Here is my code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

tree(0,[]).
tree(N, [Lt, Rt]) :-
   N #> 0,
   N #= N1 + N2 + 1,
   N1 #>= 0, N2 #>= 0,
   tree(N1, Lt), tree(N2, Rt).
```

How can I go about converting this to a string and reformatting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use declarative IO, i.e. express your code in a DCG (Definite Clause Grammar):

```erlang
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

tree(0,[]) --> "".
tree(N, [Lt, Rt]) -->
    {N #> 0,
     N #= N1 + N2 + 1,
     N1 #>= 0, N2 #>= 0
    },
    "(", tree(N1, Lt), ".", tree(N2, Rt), ")".
```

test run:

```erlang
?- phrase(tree(2,T),S),format('~s~n',[S]).
(.(.))
T = [[], [[], []]],
S = [40, 46, 40, 46, 41, 41] ;
((.).)
T = [[[], []], []],
S = [40, 40, 46, 41, 46, 41] ;
false.
```

*edit*: following @PauloMoura suggestion: add the directive

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

and enjoy a simplified interface:

```erlang
?- phrase(tree(2,T),S).
T = [[], [[], []]],
S = ['(', '.', '(', '.', ')', ')'] ;
T = [[[], []], []],
S = ['(', '(', '.', ')', '.', ')'] ;
false.
```

Comment: Nice straight-forward solution. It may be worth to mention the `double_quotes` flag in it.